# Dotnet build fails, citing old non existent files from other git branch

Tags: .net, git

Basically the title, trying to run

```
dotnet build -c release --no-restore -o /app
```

it fails with multiple cases of the errors CS0246 and CS0234, complaining about the type / namespace in files that doesn't exist. They existed previously on another branch in the same git repo. Restore runs right before without a problem.

All of them seem to be about the fact that the other branch was using EF and DB Contexts, added examples below.

The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

'IdentityDbContext' could not be found

The type or namespace name 'IDataProtectionKeyContext' could not be found

The type or namespace name 'DbContextOptions<>' could not be found

Comment: Having you tried deleting the obj and bin files completely before running anything else?

Comment: @JonSkeet It has not helped, edited question to show some examples, and it seems like all of them have to do with the other branch using EF and DbContexts, if that helps.

Comment: Did you actually switch to a different branch? Or perhaps the files are mixed up? Perhaps some source files weren't added to source control so they remain the same in all branches?

Comment: There really isn't anything for us to go on here. Where is your build running, locally or on CI? Have you ensured you've checked out the repo to a new clean directory? Have you ensured the repo is on the correct branch? There are just so many possibilities and you've apparently done nothing to eliminate any of them.

Comment: One thing is certain - this has nothing to do with Entity Framework or any library. It's purely a git/source code issue.

Comment: @IanKemp The branch is checked out, build is running locally, and none of the files referenced are present in the repo at all in this branch.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That might be the case, added EF because after looking at it, all the errors are regarding files that I added working with it.

Comment: @PatchingMatching because those are the untracked files. You'd get the same error if you used any other class from a library that wasn't added to the project.

Comment: I'm glad you guys pointed me towards git being the issue. Recloning the entire repo worked, but I don't get it. I removed bin and obj, didn't do anything. dotnet clean didn't do anything. And the files / code was nowhere to be found in the entire repo at that point...